# Wrong field accepted in UDP client/server app

Tags: java

I am trying to make two Java applications communicate but I am having some issues when I run it. If I run the program and type "Hello" the program prompts me to enter the username but it takes the input as the password. This is an example of what my output looks like:

```
What is your initial message
Hello
Welcome to Keene State Server, what is your username?
Alice
Incorrect password. Please try again.
```

My desired output is:

```
What is your initial message
Hello
Welcome to Keene State Server, what is your username?
Alice
User name is OK, what is your password?
123456
Password is OK, you are now connected to the network
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClientProcess {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //Asks user for what their initial message is
        System.out.println("What is your initial message");
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
        while(true) {
            //create a new client socket and Gets the IP address of the computer on which the other
            //process in running 
            //in this case, it's localhost because both two processes (client and server) are running
            //on the same local host

            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

            the data message we will send is from the user input

            String username = inFromUser.readLine();
            sendData = username.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress,                      
            5000);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String response = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();

            //if the response is good it will ask for the password
            if (response.equals("User name is OK, what is your password?")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter your password:");
                String password = inFromUser.readLine();
                sendData = password.getBytes();
                sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 5000);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

                receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                response = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
                System.out.println(response);
            } else {
                System.out.println(response);
            }
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
}



import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ServerProcess {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //In the server process, a DatagramSocket object must also be instantiated 
        //and bound to a local port number which is 5000 in this case.  
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5000);

        while(true) {
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

            //Receives data messages sent to the server packet
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            String username = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
            String response = "";

            //If stetment that takes the input and chooses what to display
            if (username.equals("Hello")) {
                response = "Welcome to the Server, what is your username?";
            } else if (username.equals("Alice")) {
                response = "User name is OK, what is your password?";
            } else {
                response = "Invalid username. Please try again.";
            }

            sendData = response.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);

            receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            port = receivePacket.getPort();

            String password = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();

            if (password.equals("123456")) {
                response = "Password is OK, you are now connected to the network";
            } else {
                response = "Incorrect password. Please try again.";
            }

            sendData = response.getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed "using the command line" from question, since it sounded like they were trying to communicate using e.g. stdout.

Comment: In the future, when diagnosing an issue, you should try to remove as many lines from your code as you can while still demonstrating the issue. Many times this will help you solve the issue before you even post on StackOverflow, and if you do end up posting on SO, it will make readers far happier.

Comment: You should not do this, You should collect the username and password first, and send them in one datagram. Validating the username before collecting the password constitutes an information leak to an attacker. Security 101. And the valiidation should consist of a yes or no, not a message saying that one is OK but not the other, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, you need to repeat the username logic if you receive "hello".

In your `if` logic,

```
            if (username.equals("Hello")) {
                response = "Welcome to the Server, what is your username?";
```

and send the response, but you don't listen for the username again after sending it - you expect the next datagram you receive to be the password.

Answer (score 0):

Change ServerProcess and your flow should work

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ServerProcess {
    private static final String PASSWD_PROMPT = "User name is OK, what is your password?";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //In the server process, a DatagramSocket object must also be instantiated 
        //and bound to a local port number which is 5000 in this case.  
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = null;
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = null;
        
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        String response = "";

        while(true) {

            //Receives data messages sent to the server packet
            receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            String username = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();

            //If stetment that takes the input and chooses what to display
            if (username.equals("Hello")) {
                response = "Welcome to the Server, what is your username?";
            } else if (username.equals("Alice")) {
                response = PASSWD_PROMPT;
            } else {
                response = "Invalid username. Please try again.";
            }

            sendData = response.getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            if(PASSWD_PROMPT.equals(response)) break;
        }
        
        while(true) {
            //Receives data messages sent to the server packet
            receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            String password = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();

            if (password.equals("123456")) {
                response = "Password is OK, you are now connected to the network";
            } else {
                response = "Incorrect password. Please try again.";
            }

            sendData = response.getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            
        }
    }
}
```